# Compiled Query return type not implicitly convertible

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I have written the following compiled query for my code-first entity model. However, I need help getting this to correctly compile. Below is the code for my class and then the compiled query I wrote to query the BudgetContext Object for this information

```
[DataContract]
public class BudgetSummary : IBudgetSummary, IEntity
{
    public int Id{ get()}
    public int MDACode{ get; set; }

    public DateTime BudgetYear{ get; set; }

    public virtual IList<IBudgetItem> budgetitems{ get; set; }

}

public class BudgetContext : DbContext
{ 
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<BudgetItem> BudgetItems { get; set; }
    public DbSet<BudgetLineItem> BudgetLineItems { get; set; }
    public DbSet<IBudgetSummary> BudgetSummaries { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MDA> MDAs { get; set; }

}



    static readonly Func<BudgetContext, int, IQueryable<BudgetSummary>> FindBudgetSummaryCompiledQuery =
CompiledQuery.Compile<BudgetContext,int, IQueryable<BudgetSummary>>(
        (ctx, mdaID) => from budgetsummary in ctx.BudgetSummaries
                        where budgetsummary.MDACode >= mdaID
                        select budgetsummary);
```

**Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type 'System.Func>' because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type**

Comment: Uninformed guess: your syntax highlighting in the lambda looks screwy (the 'where' is not highlighted as a keyword.)  Do you have using System.Linq at the top?

Comment: @jlew syntax highlighting is done by SO

Comment: Oh, true.  Funny it got 'from' and 'select' correct though.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

According to the link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/02/ef-4-1-is-coming-dbcontext-api-amp-code-first-rtw.aspx

**1) No compiled query support from DbContext** 
Unfortunately due to some technical limitations in the compiled query functionality we shipped in .NET Framework 4.0 we are unable to support compiled queries via the DbContext API. We realize this is a painful limitation and will work to enable this for the next release.